# Change text area content depends on selected values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have one form. In this form contains textarea and dropdown field. When I select multiple options from this dropdown that values are show inside this textarea and when i deselect options from dropdown they are removed from textarea. But now my problem is when I edit or add content to this textarea after that I could not add selected values to this textarea with already user entered data.

I want to see `textarea` content as entered text + selected value.

How is it possible.?

My code here:

```
 <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <title>val demo</title>
     <style>
      p {
      color: red;
      margin: 4px;
      }
      b {
       color: blue;
      }
     </style>
     <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
     <textarea id="test"></textarea>
     <select id="multiple" multiple="multiple">
       <option selected="selected">Multiple</option>
  <option>Multiple2</option>
  <option selected="selected">Multiple3</option>
</select>
<script>
function displayVals() {
  var singleValues = $( "#single" ).val();
  var multipleValues = $( "#multiple" ).val() || [];
  $( "#test" ).val( multipleValues.join( ", " ) );
}

$( "select" ).change( displayVals );
displayVals();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you want custom text and selected box value combine in textarea ?

Comment: The text will be from static ( from page load it will be ) or you want to enter dynamic like from textbox ?

Comment: And also do you want to just keep appending indefinitely (like the examples below) or do you want to just have "entered text"+"selected text" and change the selected text bit only?

Comment: yes I want entered text+selected text and change only selected text bit only.

Comment: what about if we use div for result ?

Comment: No use only text area because if we use 'div' means how do we enter custom text. If is it possible means share your answer

Comment: you can use textarea for custom text but your result will be displayed on div not in textarea.

Comment: ok sir can you post your code here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <title>val demo</title>
     <style>
      p {
      color: red;
      margin: 4px;
      }
      b {
       color: blue;
      }
     </style>
     <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
     <textarea id="test"></textarea>
     <div id="result"></div>
     <select id="multiple" multiple="multiple">
       <option selected="selected">Multiple</option>
  <option>Multiple2</option>
  <option selected="selected">Multiple3</option>
</select>
<script>
function displayVals() {
  // $( "#test" ).val() = '';
  var singleValues = $( "#test" ).val();
  var multipleValues = $( "#multiple" ).val() || [];
  $( "#result" ).html(singleValues+' '+ multipleValues.join( ", " ) );
}

$( "select" ).change( displayVals );
displayVals();
</script>
```

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/EZoboBe/1/edit)

Comment: I want to  display content inside the text area Is it possible?

Comment: If I want to show content like this format (selected value + entered text + selected value + selected value + entered text ... ), How can I do this?

Comment: no if I enter text between two selected values then the text show at  beginning of text area content.

Answer (score 1):

you want to have  textarea content as entered text + selected value. so it should be like shown below

```
 var currentTextVal = $("#test").val();
 var multipleValues = $("#multiple").val() || [];
 $("#test").val( currentTextVal + ' , ' + multipleValues.join(", "));
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove options values from text before rewrite them :

```
function displayVals() {
  var multipleValues = $( "#multiple" ).val() || [];
  var test =  $( "#test" ).val();
  console.log("#test = " + test);

  for (i = $( "option" ).length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      console.log($($("option")[i]).val());    
      test = test.replace($($("option")[i]).val() + ", ", "");  
      test = test.replace($($("option")[i]).val(), "");       
  }     

  $( "#test" ).val( test.trim() + " " + multipleValues.join( ", " ) );
}

$( "select" ).change( displayVals );
displayVals();
```

JSFIDDLE : http://jsfiddle.net/Pascalz/RfeGK/2/